# Tabulator - responsive - Height of table

Tags: height, responsive, tabulator

I really like tabulator but cant seem to get it to adjust to the height of the device. If I fix a height

e.g. 
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"600px",

If obviously looks bigger on a mobile etc

Is there a way of making the table 90% or whatever of the window height ?
cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can set the height as a percentage:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", { height:"100%",
```

The ***height*** property will take any valid CSS height value